# Using PHP to transform a 3D array into a 2D one

Tags: php, arrays

My form produces a 3 dimensional array. I would like to transform this array into a 2 dimensional one.

I tried this with no success:

```
$_rows = array();
foreach ($_contacts as $name => $_arr) {
   foreach ($_arr as $key => $val) {
        $_rows[] = array ($name => $val);
   }
}
```

Data Source:

```
[_contacts] => Array
    (

    [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => foo
                [1] => bar
            )

    [phone] => Array
            (
                [0] => 012345
                [1] => 098765
            )

    [email] => Array
            (
                [0] => mail.com
                [1] => yahoo.com
            )
    )
```

Desired output:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => foo
                [phone] => 012345
                [email] => mail.com
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => bar
                [phone] => 098765
                [email] => yahoo.com
            )
    )
```

Any thoughts were I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_rows = array();     
foreach ($_contacts as $name => $_arr) {          
   foreach ($_arr as $key => $val) {            
        $_rows[$key][$name] = $val;
   }
}
```

Comment: One more thing please. As I can not create an array like this (empty)? array ( [name] => [phone] => [email]=> )? thanks

Comment: You can use something like `array('name' => null, 'phone' => null, 'email' => null)` or `array('name' => '', 'phone' => '', 'email' => '')`

Comment: I'd like to skip to create 2nd level array if the 3d level is empty. [_contacts] => Array
    (

    [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => foo
                [1] => 
            )

    [phone] => Array
            (
                [0] => 012345
                [1] => 
            )

    [email] => Array
            (
                [0] => mail.com
                [1] => 
            )
    )